# Localise App Store App Name when name is taken

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, internationalization

When adding a new app to the App Store, I usually use the `English (UK)` localisation as I’m in the UK. Searching for the app name I plan to use, I see it’s already taken, but I’m assuming only for the `English (US)` localisation as App Store Connect let’s me set it for my app.
If I add `English (US)` localisation to my app, it then complains the app name is taken.

Is there any downside to using just 1 localisation?
Will both apps show up on the App Store under all localisations as they are set to just 1?